# How to set rownames as column in the list of dataframes?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have list of dataframes (List of 4) in global environment for match data called **match_list**. I wanted to transpose the list with `match_list <- lapply(match_list,t)` so it makes metrics as colnames.

[image: This is the output [![enter image description here][1]][1]]

It transposed the dataframe in each list but it also made previous colnames as rownames. Could you please helped me how to get rid off the rownames? And make it as a standard column?

I am then performing for loop

```
#### create individual dataframes ----
for (i in seq(match_list))
  assign(paste0(file_names[[i]]), match_list[[i]])
```

that creates separate dataframes in my global environment

I have tried several ways, but still cannot turn my head around to make it work.

My attempt:

```
match_list <- lapply(match_list,function(x){
  
  colnames(x) <- rownames_to_column(match_list[[1]]) 
  
})
```

This is my whole script:

````
match_xlsx <- as_tibble(list.files("C:/Users/User/Desktop/asJohan", pattern = ".xlsx", full.names = TRUE, all.files = FALSE))
file_names <- list.files("C:/Users/User/Desktop/asJohan", pattern = ".xlsx", full.names = TRUE, all.files = FALSE)


#### read specific sheet from excel ---- create two lists and merge them
match_list <- lapply(match_xlsx$value, read_excel, sheet = 1, range = "B1:N40")
match_list <- lapply(match_list,t) 
#match_list <- lapply(match_list, function(x) {x <- x[-1,-1 ]}) #### remove first column and row




###set first row as a header - column names
match_list <- lapply(match_list, function(x){
colnames(x) <- x[1,]
x[-(1:3),]})

####set rowname as column name

match_list <- lapply(match_list, rownames_to_column, var='former_transposed_colnames')


#### create individual dataframes ----
for (i in seq(match_list))
assign(paste0(file_names[[i]]), match_list[[i]])```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `rownames_to_column` (if the one from the `tibble`-package), *returns* the input data.frame, in this case, the one in `match_list[[1]]`. Instead, you are trying to push the entire data.frame into the vector of colnames (the `colnames(x) <-`-portion).

Instead, you can simply use

```
match_list <- lapply(match_list, rownames_to_column)
```

and the default behaviour of `rownames_to_column` will assign the rownames to a column named `rownames`. You can change this with e.g.

```
match_list <- lapply(match_list, rownames_to_column, var='former_transposed_colnames')
```

**Edit:**

You can convert your list back to data.frames with... `lapply`:

```
match_list <- lapply(match_list,t)
match_list <- lapply(match_list,as.data.frame)
match_list <- lapply(match_list, rownames_to_column)

# or if you load dplyr 
library(dplyr)
match_list <- lapply(match_list, t) %>%
  lapply(as.data.frame) %>%
  lapply(rownames_to_column)
```

But rather than use `t` to transpose (as it requires all entries having the same data.type, i.e. everything becomes character because a column was a string, try using `tidyr`'s `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`. This will however require you have an id-column (prior to `pivot_longer`), but I suspect you might already have one in the first column (in column 'A', which you at some point remove). If you do not, you can create a dummy id-column by simply numbering the rows. When you are done, remove the dummy values.

Comment: Hello, thank you for time to answer. I have tested but I have an issue with rownames_to_column() as it works just for dataframes. Do you think I can pass list with rowname_to_column becasue it gives me this error Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : is.data.frame(df) is not TRUE

Comment: I see the error; I missed you had used `t` on all the data.frames - `t` *only* returns matrices. So my current solution will not work.

Comment: No problem at all, I have added to question an update how my whole script looks. I have used t() to transpose. Much thanks

Comment: @MrGrumble - thank you a lot that worked! Awesome.